# How to insert data in cosmos DB with azure JavaScript function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-function-app

I am trying to insert data from azure javascript function app to cosmos DB.
This is the function.json File

```
 {
 "bindings": [
  {
  "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
  "name": "documents",
  "direction": "in",
  "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
  "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection",
  "databaseName": "roi",
  "collectionName": "reports",
  "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": "true"
  },
  {
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "res"
  }
 ]
}
```

index.js have a code like this.

```
module.exports = async function (context, documents) {
     if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
    context.log('Document Id: ', documents[0].id);
  }
 }
```

Below images will have the error in the application.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any function or query to insert the data ? the request data which is coming from api will look like this.(its coming in rawBody property of request)

[image]

When i am fetching the data its workign fine.

```
{
  "name": "inputDocumentIn",
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "databaseName": "roi",
  "collectionName": "reports",
  "sqlQuery": "SELECT * from reports r",
  "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

local.setting.json file

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
 "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
 "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
 "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
 "CosmosDBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=.....;"
 },
"Host": {
 "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
 "CORS": "*"
 }
}
```

With this azure value in local.setting.ts file , i m getting following error.
[image]

Comment: Can you share which Nuget packages you have in your extensions.csproj file?

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the Connection String is pointing to the correct account and check if it was caused by the firewall and networks. Go to your cosmos db account on azure portal and click "Firewall and virtual networks". You can select "All networks" or "Selected networks" with your current IP filled in it.

Comment: but when i am fetching the result its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some some dependency conflict. Could you do a `dotnet clean` on the project folder and then verify that all projects (in case you have project dependencies) have the latest version of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB) (currently 3.0.5)?

Comment: do you have any git repo for this probelm ?

Comment: The Functions Extension's github repo is https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the above problem is :
I have changed function.json file with this code.

```
{
"bindings": [
 {
  "authLevel": "anonymous",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "methods": [ "post" ],
  "name": "req"
 },
 {
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "res"
 },
 {
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "outputDocument",
  "databaseName": "roi",
  "collectionName": "reports",
  "createIfNotExists": true,
  "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection",
  "direction": "out",
  "partitionKey": "/id"
  }
 ],
 "disabled": false
}
```

and the request coming from front end will be manipulate like this.

```
  module.exports =  function (context, req) {
    if (req.body) {
    context.bindings.outputDocument = req.body;
    var responseBody = {};
    responseBody.message =  "Wow! data with  id '" + req.body.id + "' was created!";

    context.res = {
        status: 201, 
        body:responseBody
    };
   }
  else {
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: { "message" : "Please pass a valid  object in the request body"}
    };
  }
 context.done();
 }
```

Comment: its an answer of the question